# Automatically add formatting to input field as user types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My application is Angular 1.3.10

I am currently adding a backslash to the expiration input field with a jQuery function, see below.

The expiration input is formatted for MM/YY and the '/' is automatically added once the user types the third number. It was a quick fix, but I need to move it into $scope.  I've gave it the good ol' college try but am blocked, so I am hoping those much smarter than me can lend a hand.

Current jQuery code I need to move to Angular $scope:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cc-exp").keypress(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }
    });
});
```

The expiration html input field:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Expiration MM/YY</label>
    <input ng-model="expiration" id="cc-exp" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/"  name="expiration" type="tel" class="long cc-exp" minlength="5" maxlength="5" required>
    <div ng-messages="payment.expiration.$error" ng-if="payment.$submitted" class="validation-error-display">
       <div ng-message="required">Please enter an expiration date.</div>
       <div ng-message="pattern">Must contain numbers only.</div>
       <div ng-message="minlength">Must be MM/YY format.</div>
       <div ng-message="maxlength">Must be MM/YY format.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: why not use `ui-mask` and mask the date input field

Answer (score 0):

How about using $scope.$watch, this function will be called every time the expiration is changed:

```
$scope.$watch('expiration',function(newValue, oldValue){
      if(newValue.length == 2) $scope.expiration = $scope.expiration +'/';
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0):

Using directive would be good choice

**Markup**

```
<input ng-model="expiration" id="cc-exp" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/"  name="expiration" 
my-dir type="tel" class="long cc-exp" minlength="5" maxlength="5" required>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.on('keypress', function(e) {
                var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
                if (val.length == 2) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(val + "/");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```